# Calculation of an integral with Gamma function

Tags: integration, analysis, gamma-function

Can help me to calculate this integral: $$
\int_{z}^{\infty} \exp(-l\cdot x) \Gamma(m,x) dx, \qquad 
$$
with
$$\Gamma(m,x) = \int_x^{\infty} \exp(-y) y^{m-1} dy$$
and where w,l,z positives

Comment: Does exchanging integrals work?

Comment: Maybe, bacause it is non-negative, but i dont know how to continue

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Exchanging integrals doesn't work because $\int_z^{\infty} e^{-l x} \left(\int_x^{\infty} e^{-y}\, y^{m-1}\,dy\right) dx\neq\int_x^{\infty} e^{-y}\, y^{m-1} \left(\int_z^{\infty} e^{-l x}\,dx\right) dy$ since the outer integral on the right-hand side is a function of $x$ which is the lower integration limit.

Comment: Why do you think it's possible to calculate the first integral using the second integral?

Comment: I assume you meant "where m,l,z positives" versus "where w,l,z positives".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$I=\int e^{-kx}\,\Gamma(m,x)\,dx$$ Using integration by parts
$$du=e^{-kx}\,dx\quad \implies \quad u=-\frac 1 k e^{-k x}$$
$$v=\Gamma(m,x)\quad \implies \quad dv=-e^{- x} \, x^{m-1}$$
$$I=-\frac 1 k e^{-k x}\,\Gamma(m,x)-\frac 1k \int e^{-(k+1) x} \,x^{m-1}\,dx$$

Let $(k+1)x=y$ and look again at the definition of $\Gamma(m,x)$.